# Can a friend of a friend see my post?

Tags: facebook, facebook-privacy

I did not block the person I do not want to see my post. I want to know if a specific person, who I am NOT friends with,can see my post if a mutual friend likes it or comments on it. I have searched trouble shooting & Facebook FAQ's & my question is NOT answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your post privacy is set to:

1. Friends: then only and only your friends can see this post and comments on it
2. Only Me: visible to only you
3. Friends of Friends: It will be shown to all your friends and their friends too. Let's say you have 100 friends and each of your friend has 50 friend then your post will be seen by maximum 100 * 50 = 5000 buddies.
4. Public: public posts and comments on those posts can be seen by anyone on the web
5. Custom: You can list out the name of friends or lists, who can see this post. Even you can filter out friends and lists.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding, I REALLY appreciate it! 
Okay, so my post is custom. Set to Friends (not Friends of Friends)  & I have a list of mutuals of this undesirable person restricted except for 2. One of those reacted to my post. If I understand.....the undesirable person will still not see this post.

Comment: If your post is "friends" with some exception, then all those "exception" list would not be able to see your post and comments on it.